# Переключение между Canvas из скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как реализовать переключение между Canvas из скрипта?

На то что написано в документации студия орет что устаревшие методы.

То что нашел в интернете все какое то старое, и по-моему можно сделать короче и проще, должны же быть для этого инструменты...

Я добавил к Canvas две Animation, on  и off в них добавил Canvas.Enable, в одной анимации он равен 1 в другой 0. Переключение между ними по тригеру в Animator, это костыль? Или вполне рабочая схема?

Но появился новый вопрос как определить какой Canvas в данный момент Enable что бы отключить его? Загнать в переменную? Как то не универсально..

Как можно получить все обьекты типа Canvas на сцене?

Comment: А можете описать, чего конкретно вы хотите добиться? Для чего вам нужно переключение между канвасами?

Comment: @M.Green для переключения между интерфейсами игровым, меню и тд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я делал систему игровых панелей выглядело всё примерно так:
У меня есть объект "UI" на нём висит соответствующим образом настроенный Canvas и компонент что-нибудь вроде UISystem. Внутри этого объекта-системы находятся уже объекты панелей. На каждой панели есть свой выключенный Canvas и класс наследующийся от общего предка APanel. Этот класс уже и осуществляет управление "появлением" и содержит идентификатор панели.

Т.е. сама система знает обо всех панелях, что являются её чайлдам и содержит в себе их список. Когда я хочу открыть панель я говорю системе "Открой панель "Меню", она ищет в этом списке по идентификатору, находит и вызывает у неё метод, например, Open();. Панель включает свой Canvas через _canvas.enable = true. Когда панель нужно закрыть - говорю системе "закрой панель такую-то" и действие описанное выше повторяется.

На самом деле, там всё было гораздо сложнее, включало отдельные скрипты "аниматоры", которые отвечали за то, как именно появляется панель, отдельные модификаторы появления (вроде "Закрыть все, а потом открыть вот эту"), кальбэки после открытия и события у панелей, чтобы можно было делать что-то в панели до/после проигрывания анимации открытия/закрытия. Однако, основная суть описана в первых двух абзацах.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Пока сидел и пытался что то сделать сделал почти то что вы написали только без главного UISystem, но передаю под вашу модель, намного практичнее... Есть одна проблема с включением Canvas на андроид... Там точно работает метод canvas.enable?... В юнити все работает однако при сборке и установке на Андроиде просто ничего не происходит.. пока грешу на canvas.enable

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, да, у меня точно работает. Соберите билд выставив галочку "DebugBuild". Возможно, у вас просто где-то ошибка выпадает или пустая ссылка и не работает вообще всё, а не конкретно ".enable". С дебаг билдом прикручивается консоль и вы увидите её в игре, если что-то случится.

Comment: Поставил галочку но консоли в игре нету, только надпись справа снизу Build developer...

Comment: Нашел ошибку, у меня в чайлде происходит поиск предка по тэгу, в нем вылетает NullException... я не понимаю как в наследнике повляется эта ошибка... он же не ожет появится раньше предка.. как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, искать не по тегу) зачем там вообще поиск по тегу? На главном канвасе висит скрипт UISystem, вот из дочерней панели его и ищите через GetComponentInParent<UISystem>(); Если и так не найдёт - значит не с того чайлда ищите. А вообще, лучше сделать общий метод доступа к системе, чтобы поиск из другого места не отличался от поиска из самой панели. Хоть тот же синглтон используйте (хотя их и ругают). Поиск по тегу обходит вообще все  объекты сцены - а это плохо для производительности.